# Pass data between two fragments without using activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I want to pass data between two fragments without using activity and fragment activity.

I don't want to pass data between fragments using activity like this : [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Below is my scenario :

I have one Parent fragment and inside that there are two child fragments.Now my need is to pass data between these two fragments.How to achieve this?

I looked into this :  [Event Bus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) but not getting working example for fragments.

Is there any other alternative to pass data between fragments?

Any help will be appreciated.

**Edited as per InnocentKiller's answer :**

In FragmentOne , I have implemented :

```
    FragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Hello", "My name is Siddharth");
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

In FragmentTwo, I have implemented :

```
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    String myInt = bundle.getString("Hello","Test");
    mStartTripButton.setText(myInt);
```

Comment: Without Activity How can you manage Fragment?

Comment: You can use Singleton/static variable

Comment: @M D : In my parent fragment, i have a layout file which has two fragments.My parent fragment is called when I click on navigation drawer.And my navigation drawer is main activity.

Comment: @M D : I dont want a call back method on my main activity, i want it inside my parent fragment. And doing this shows ClassCast exception.

Comment: Regarding EventBus, you can use the example from my answer directly. That is: in frag A `EventBus.getDefault().postSticky("Hello")` and in frag B `String hello = EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(String.class)`

Comment: Or take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20838726/how-to-use-greenrobot-to-pass-data-to-activity-or-fragment-that-has-not-been-ini

Comment: And how to pass data from FragmentOne to FragmentTwo when the data is received from server? You haven't access to data when you initiate FragmentTwo.

Answer (score 17):

Best Way to exchange data between activity/fragments, fragment/fragment/, activity/activity, class/ class, make a common singleton class like:

```
public class DataHolderClass {
private static DataHolderClass dataObject = null;

private DataHolderClass() {
    // left blank intentionally
}

public static DataHolderClass getInstance() {
    if (dataObject == null)
        dataObject = new DataHolderClass();
    return dataObject;
}
private String distributor_id;;

 public String getDistributor_id() {
    return distributor_id;
 }

 public void setDistributor_id(String distributor_id) {
    this.distributor_id = distributor_id;
 }
}
```

now set from anywhere(Fragment, activity, class) at any event before you move to new screen

```
DataHolderClass.getInstance().setDistributor_id("your data");
```

now get anywhere(Fragment, activity, class)

```
 String _data = DataHolderClass.getInstance().getDistributor_id();
```

Comment: How reliable is this method? As far as I know, there's no guarantee that a static var will retain its value. Looks very convenient though.

Comment: @jdkraftz I have not dug up the reference but I am 99% sure that the static variable is kept during the application lifecycle. At least I have been using this approach in an app that is continuously used 8 hours per day and have had no problems so far.

Answer (score 8):

You can use EventBus https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus to pass any complex object around in Android.

Example passing an object from one Activity to another:

Add your object on the EventBus:

```
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(anyObject);
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SomeActivity.class));
```

Anywhere in SomeActivity:

```
AnyObject anyObject = EventBus.getDefault().getStickyEvent(AnyObject.class);
```

This examle is just to show that it works across Activities, you can call `getStickyEvent` to get anyObject anywhere in your code.

So, you can post an object in Fragment A, and use getStickyEvent in fragment B to retrieve it.

This is especially convenient if you have a lot of arguments and/or complex objects you wish to move from one place to the other. Simply create a single 'holder' object containing getter/setters for the arguments and then pass it along. Much simpler than having to pass them separately and somehow serialize the complex objects.

Comment: +1 for a globally usable library. But it is a bit heavy for this task alone. Building your own data holder is lighter.

Comment: @SubinSebastian You are right, actually recently transitioned to temporal static holders in many cases. EventBus though offers other very nice functionality, such as broadcasting complex objects. Suddenly it is easy to, for instance, update UI based on service events. Even if wanting to communicate non trivial data.

Comment: plus it is not suitable at all for this! You can not pass data from a fragment to another without engaging the host activity which is awkward!

Comment: It may be awkward, but you can, either with this method or static holders as described by @De

Answer (score 4):

I think you are trying to pass data from one fragment to another fragment, So try using below code.

Use a Bundle, So write below code in first fragment from where you want to send data.

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "From Activity");
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and to retrieve that data, use the following code in your other fragment

```
String strtext=getArguments().getString("message");
```

Comment: This solution sounds good..will give it a try and let you know..Thanks

Comment: I am getting bundle as null.

Comment: May be the value you are passing is null, or might be some other problem. Can't say anything without seeing your code.

Comment: @SiddharthVyas But here after setting Argument you must commit your `Fragment Transaction`...

Comment: @SiddharthVyas, Check my edit, Please pass String value from your first fragment instead of Int and then in second fragment just get the Key... Do not pass any value

Comment: @InnocentKiller : Still getting NullPointer exception.