# passing data between three activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have two fragments and one activity + Main Activity

1. **1st Fragment** where new intent is created that calls **the Activity**
2. **Activity** that is called by above mentioned intent. I want to pass data here
3. **2nd Fragment** from where I want to get Strings from textviews and pass the results to **Activity** mentioned above

so the fragment that has intent does not contain the information that I want to  pass, but another fragment contains, that does not have intent.

The one solution I see is to incorporate 1st Fragment and Activity Code into MainActivity but in this case, I have to copy all my code there.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Can you please clear where are these fragments exactly

Comment: Maybe I create an inner class in 2nd fragment and access its variables in activity?

Comment: both fragments are in MainActivity

Comment: What you really want to do? get info from 2nd fragment to pass to 1st fragment?

Comment: [Check My Answer Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484245/pass-data-between-two-fragments-without-using-activity/27484940#27484940), if found useful, give a +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give tag to both fragments
You can create public method in 2nd fragment to get required text and in 1st fragment access that fragment like this

```
Fragment frag2 = getFragmentMangegetFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Frag2");
if(frag2 != null){
text = frag2.getRequiredText();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface in Fragment1 and this interface must be implement by activity. it will make communicated between Fracment1 and activity.
And in implement method you call Fragment

```
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
```

Method when buttin is clicked

```
    public void onButtonPressed() {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(data);
    }
}
```

interface which will be implement by activity

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understood your problem.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment
{
  public Intent getIntent ()
  {
    return neededIntent;
  }
}


public class Fragment2 extends Fragment
{
  public String getStringData ()
  {
    return stringData;
  }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
  public void makeIntent ()
  {
    Intent i = fragment1.getIntent ();
    String data = fragment2.getStringData ();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanna pass data from 2nd `Fragment` to it father `Activity` you can do as below:

```
//in 2nd Fragmnet you can call whenever you want:
if(getActivity() != null && getActivity() instanceof  FatherActivity){
     // You can create setYourData in your Father Activity.
     ((FatherActivity)getActivity()).setYourData(yourData);         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are U asking about this ? see this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html