# Populating a listview in a different fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have this code, which gets data from various `EditTexts` and adds this info into a ListView_item in fragment 1. This ListView_item is supposed to be populated in the ListView in fragment 2. I was thinking this might be possible with the help of the EventBus library but I have not quite yet gotten my head around how.

Here is my populate list method

```
public void populateList() {
    ArrayAdapter<Appointment> adapter = new AppointmentListAdapter();
    (The listview in fragment 2).setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: pass your data between two fragments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484245/pass-data-between-two-fragments-without-using-activity

Comment: The simplest way to do so is make a custom adapter and  use it.

Comment: Rahul Patidar can you give me an example

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do this :

1) Using Interface: You will find lots of links for how to use interface for data passing.

2) Pass adapter through the activity :

step 1 : In your Fragment1 Make getParent() method :

```
private MyActivity getParent() {
        return ((MyActivity) getActivity());
}
```

step 2 : In MyActivity Make populateList() method :

```
public void populateList(ArrayAdapter<Appointment> adapter){
        SecondFragment mSecondFragment = (SecondFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(SecondFragment.TAG);
        mSecondFragment.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

step 3 : In your Fragment1 populateList method look like below :

```
public void populateList() {
        ArrayAdapter<Appointment> adapter = new AppointmentListAdapter();
        getParent().populateList(adapter);
}
```