# extras string from fragment one to last fragment

Tags: android

Easy way to pass data(e.g.string) from fragment one to last fragment, I mean ,how to (save, set or put ) data, and (show, get ) in the last fragment, I used arguments  to pass from  fragment 1  to fragment two, but I don´t have any idea how to pass to last fragment .

Answer (score 1):

you can pass values by Bundle.

for example:

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
fragment.setArguments(args);
FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.add(R.id.container_layout, fragment);
ft.commit();
```

if you dont want to add or replace fragment. (incase if your fragment is already open) then you can make Interface in that fragment and implement Interface on your BaseActivity.

Comment: ok let my try, and thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

pass value

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentManager manager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
fragment.setArguments(args);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.replace(R.id.container_layout, fragment).commit();
```

get value

```
 @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            yourvalue1 = getArguments().getString("ARG_PARAM1");
            yourvalue2 = getArguments().getString("ARG_PARAM2");
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, container, false);
       retrun view;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data from any fragment to any fragment with Bundles as per suggested by another answer, as per [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) suggested communication pattern.

Or you can make singleton and can access variables from it,see my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39428135/5476209)
it is already several time asked question,so please search first before directly asking question.

Comment: thanks dude and apologies for ask, it´s my first day :)

Comment: U r welcome to SO community please spent 5 minutes on this to get guidelines for how to ask question. here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask